# Open swift app from URL with properties and load specific VC

Tags: swift, properties, url-scheme

Working on an application for iOS at the moment, I stumbled across the following problem: Users should be able to open the app with a specific URL scheme (`demoapp://`), passing an url as a property (`demoapp://google.de`).

I accomplished that with the following code:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var host: String!

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

        host = url.host
        print(host)

        return true

}

[...]
```

However, afterwards, I want to show a specific ViewController (`AddUrlViewController`) with the link filled in the textfield `urlFieldOutlet`.

I can't find a way to show a different VC than the main one.

Comment: Your requirement is too vague. It all depends on what your app is currently showing at the time this app delegate method is called and how you want `AddUrlViewController` displayed.

Comment: This should work in any case, i.e. if the app starts from scratch (it initially shows the `ViewController.swift`) or if it is running already. The `AddUrlViewController` can be reached from `ViewController` with 

```@IBAction func circularAddButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        
        // Go to add screen
        Haptic.impact(.medium).generate()
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "HomeToAddSegue", sender: nil)
        
}
```